# Accessing variable assigned in a function

Tags: python, function, variables

I have a function like:

```
def function():
  var_a = 1
  var_b = 2
  var_c = 3
  return var_a, var_b, var_c
```

The purpose of the function is to assign to some variables. I need to be able to call on the function for quick assignment and then be able to use those variables in the rest of my code. However, if I now try:

```
function()
print(var_a)
```

I get an error message telling me that var_a is not defined.

If I instead try

```
values = function()
print(values)
```

this displays the values as a tuple, but doesn't give me access to separate values in separate variables. How can I make it work the way I want?

Comment: When you run the function, why are you not saving the returned values? `var_a, var_b, var_c = function()`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Repeat your tutorial on functions to learn how to use the values you return to the main program.

Comment: Are you expecting global variables to be assigned/created by calling `function`? You have to declare each variable as global with something like `global var_a, var_b, var_c` at the beginning of the function to avoid creating local variables.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the values that you return from the function.

```
a, b, c = function()
```

If you assign the three values to a single tuple, you can also destructure them from the tuple the same way:

```
values = function()
a, b, c = values
```